# Imploding and matching array with another array

Tags: php, arrays

Say I've got one array like this

```
$users_names=array(1=>"Abby",2=>"Betty",3=>"Cathy",4=>"Debby");
```

And another like this

```
$users_admin=array(1,3);
```

What is the best way to implode the $users_admin array matching to $users_names?

For example, I would want to do something like this:

```
echo implode(", ",magical_array_function($users_admin,$users_names));

//echos: "Abby, Cathy"
```

What I've been doing is this...

```
foreach ($users_admin as $id_user) $toEcho.=$users_names[$id_user].", ";
echo substr($toEcho,0,-2);
```

But I know there must be a more efficient way to do it in one line

Comment: Look into `array_keys()`

Comment: I use array_keys() all the time.  Just re-read the info on it.  Still wouldn't know how to do what I'm trying to do.  Want to try to submit an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `array_intersect_key` here.

```
array_intersect_key($users_names, array_flip($users_admin))
```

Comment: That does it!  thanks Rocket!  Will submit as answer when I'm able

Comment: @rgbflawed: `Will submit as answer when I'm able` - This made me think you were going to add an answer saying "Hey! It works, thnx for the solution!". Many people *actually* do that, so I was just making sure. Sorry!